# Deserialize Google Protobuf wire message on existing object

Tags: java, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I have a Java application and want to re-use existing object to deserialize incoming Google protobuf wire message (byte[]).

I am trying to decode existing wire message and check methods inside generated Class file to see if there is any method to deserialize byte[] on already created ProtoBuf Class object.

I am deserializing incoming wire buffer (byte[]) but everytime I call parseFrom on class it creates new object of Protobuf class. I wanted to reuse the class object. I tried with calling parseFrom(byte[]) method on object but as its a static method the behavior is same.

Here is sample deserializeMessage() method:

```
 public boolean deserializeMessage(byte[] wireMessage) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException
 { 
    // mktDataMsg = mktDataMsg.parseFrom(wireMessage); ==> Creates new object 
    mktDataMsg = MktDataMessage.parseFrom(wireMessage); 
    // Above code also creates new object of MktDataMessage. I want to 
    // decode wireMesage on existing object and overwrite field
    // values. That will avoid extra GC objects.
    return true;
 }
```

Is there any option to re-use object to decode incoming wire mesage (byte[])?

These are my performance numbers when Serializing & Deserializing 100k messages in Java and running iteration 10times and getting Avg of all numbers.

```
Msg Size|Total Data Processed (Mb)|Java Serialize Time|Java Deserialize Time
195     |19.5                     |                 19|                   45
1095    |109.5                    |                 84|                  132
2095    |209.5                    |                160|                  233
3095    |309.5                    |                230|                  294
4095    |409.5                    |                847|                 2465
5095    |509.5                    |               1037|                 3006
6095    |609.5                    |               1266|                 3766
```

Comment: You'll only get to reuse the builder, which is just a pointer. I bet you have a strong background in C. You don't have to worry, this is incredibly cheap for a modern garbage collector. Benchmark it and you'll see.

Comment: You got me right about 'C'.
Yeah, I did performance test and numbers are not good when message size > 4095bytes (around that) when trying to deserialize ~100k messages. The deserialization jumps from 295ms to 2,465ms (2.5seconds). There is jump in serialization as well from 230ms => 847ms (not much but it is not linear). 

I suspect its something to do with Pagesize (4K) or L1/L2 cache - but not there yet. So was focusing more on optimizing Deserialization.

I tried MessagePack as well and processing time is good linear increase based on message size + total number of message.

Comment: It is really a bit strange indeed. I'm currently running some threads deserializing 125KB proto messages in an average of 1187 microseconds/message,  in a t2.nano machine (1 "vcpu", 512MB ram). Tested, one of those threads deserialized an average of 2.5GB of proto messages (125KB as well) in a minute with no worries for two days, deserializing being one of the fastest steps in the whole "message process loop", and cpu and memory metrics being perfectly stable. What's your JVM heap size? Hmm just read the MsgPack comment... so it may be not related to jvm..

Comment: JVM Heap size is default. I am not setting any specific value:

This is what i see:
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}

Comment: Hmm cannot really tell wether it's a gc/memory issue or not. It could as well be related to the format of the protobuff message, objects in it,....